# C sfunction & RTLAB

Tags: c, matlab, real-time, simulink

I wrote a C sfunction and used it as a simulink block.It was OK.the answer is OK with the error about 10^-14 (in matlab enviroment)... Now I want to connect to RT_LAB, to run my model real time.

To execute a simulink model in RT_LAB, we have 3 steps: 1. compile the model. 2. load it. 3.execute the model. So if you have an invalid model U should have errors in 1st step (as I had before completing my model), my model compiles with no errors now, I load it, but when I execute it, the answers are not valid (there is no error but not a valid answer either).

When RT_LAB compiles a model, it translates the model to C codes. I think maybe there is something wrong with this part, generating wrong C code. Is any one here who used RT_LAB? 
How can I find the problem?

Comment: Couldn't you use proper punctuation and spacing? Is that so hard?

Comment: Sorry. I will try more :) .

Answer (score 0):

I defined my functions like this :

```
void my_fun (int input1,float *input2,....,long double *output1,....)
{
/*

my codes....

*/

return;
}
```

in C Sfunnction our inputs and outputs are kind of pointers which are defined in `"simstruc.h"` and there in stead of int Sfuntion uses int_T or in stead of float or double or long double it uses real_T, and I noticed that all the default functions in Sfunction were the `static void` and there is no `return` for them, so I changed the way I was writing my codes to :

```
static void my_fun (int_T input1,real_T *input2,....,real_T *output1,....)
    {
    /*

    my codes....

    */

    }
```

and that was the answer for my case.as a conclusion, if you are just writing Sfuntions for using in MATLAB environment there is no difference if you choose the first or the second type of writing your header functions, but if you want to compile it vie `RTLAB`, you must be care full to choose the second method.